# React native project is not working on my external device

Tags: react-native

I created a new react native project with react-native init and when I react-native run-android on my external phone it give me an error. I am using Visual Studio Code
[image: This is my error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

and then:

```
react-native start
```

and reload the app.

Comment: I did this. one terminal for react-native start and one for react-native run-android